# Best way currently to create an ansible inventory from terraform

Tags: ansible, terraform

I have a long list of machines, all of which are a little different in functionality in a system.  I'd like to organize these machines and add to a hosts inventory file automatically so I can run ansible and manage inventory.  Are there good solutions out there for this?

I think ansible hosts should looks something like...

```
[webservers]
someip
someip
[integration]
someip
someip
```

etc..

After asking the question, I currently am researching output vars and using those to render a template from a file.

Comment: can you add a bit of detail about how your terraform is organized and how your expect your inventory file to be organized? if you output machine IPs from terraform you can use the command `terraform output <identifier>` to return a list of IPs that can be a set of inventory for your playbooks.

Comment: That is helpful.  Actually I am thinking that perhaps I should use a combinations of templates and output variables to render.  I found the following repo with code https://github.com/opencredo/k8s-terraform-ansible-sample/tree/master/terraform where the person renders an ssh configuration.

Comment: just so you know you can also run playbooks from inside terraform using a null_configuration resource.

Comment: Are you aware of this: https://github.com/adammck/terraform-inventory? I found it some time ago by browsing Terraform tags on Github (cool feature by the way).

Comment: No, that is a pretty slick idea, converting it over with a terraform state file. I also appreciate the note from RaGe about running ansible using the null resource.  It sounds like a nice trick, but how you would only run it if state is changed in that scenario - not sure.

Comment: You add a trigger to the null_resource that depends on the pertinent resource. an EC2 instance for example. Whenever the EC2 is recreated, the null_resource is triggered. This is sort of off-topic here, if you post a new question I will post a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 35):

I figured it out.

```
data "template_file" "dev_hosts" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/templates/dev_hosts.cfg")}"
  depends_on = [
    "aws_instance.dev-api-gateway",
    "aws_instance.dev-api-gateway-internal",
    ....
  ]
  vars {
    api_public = "${aws_instance.dev-api-gateway.private_ip}"
    api_internal = "${aws_instance.dev-api-gateway-internal.private_ip}"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "dev-hosts" {
  triggers {
    template_rendered = "${data.template_file.dev_hosts.rendered}"
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${data.template_file.dev_hosts.rendered}' > dev_hosts"
  }
}
```

Then create a template in the file referenced earlier

Contents of example dev_hosts.cfg

```
[public]
${api_public}


[private]
${api_internal}
```

Comment: Note that if you are using Terraform on Windows (unlucky you!) via something like Git Bash you also need to add `interpreter = ["sh", "-c"]`, otherwise it will use `cmd` and will fail to save the file.

Comment: Another hint: if you have a list (for example if you use `count`) and not a single IP, then you need to interpolate it to simple value - a string in the `vars` section. This is how to do it: `servers = "${join("\n", module.servers.server_ip)}"`

Comment: Expanding on that, if you have a list and want a complex expression, you can do something like this: `"${join("\n", [for instance in aws_instance.web-servers : join("", [instance.tags.Name, " ansible_host=", instance.public_ip])] )}"`

Answer (score 28):

Since Terraform 0.12+ there is `templatefile` function that comes handy, especially if you need to populate host groups:

```
# generate inventory file for Ansible
resource "local_file" "hosts_cfg" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/hosts.tpl",
    {
      kafka_processors = aws_instance.kafka_processor.*.public_ip
      test_clients = aws_instance.test_client.*.public_ip
    }
  )
  filename = "../ansible/inventory/hosts.cfg"
}
```

Where hosts.tpl template file (future Ansible inventory) may look like this:

```
[kafka_broker_hosts]
%{ for ip in kafka_processors ~}
${ip}
%{ endfor ~}

[test_client_hosts]
%{ for ip in test_clients ~}
${ip}
%{ endfor ~}
```

End result:

```
[kafka_broker_hosts]
18.224.140.239
18.224.140.234

[test_client_hosts]
3.21.134.83
```

Comment: Is there a way to add hostsnames with count using this approach,for example:
[kafka_broker_hosts]
kafka-1 18.224.140.239
kafka-2 18.224.140.234

[test_client_hosts]
test-1 3.21.134.83

Comment: if the resources are created using `for_each` option instead of count, content should be manipulated like this `workernode = values(aws_instance.kafka_processor)[*].public_ip`

Answer (score 19):

Our approach is slightly different. We define a Terraform Module (`terraform-null-ansible`) which calls ansible anytime we want to run a playbook on a host by using a dynamic inventory.

https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-null-ansible

This is a very terraform-centric approach but leads to very clean integration. Plus, by calculating the checksum of the playbook, we only call the ansible provisioner when the playbook has changed.

Usage is quite easy:

```
module "web_provisioner" {
   source    = "git::https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-null-ansible.git?ref=tags/0.3.8"

   arguments = ["--user=ubuntu"]
   envs      = ["host=${aws_instance.web.public_ip}"]
   playbook  = "../ansible/playbooks/test.yml"
   dry_run   = false
}
```

More docs are on the GitHub `README.md`

Answer (score 6):

For multi severs:

### File inventory.tf

```
data  "template_file" "k8s" {
    template = "${file("./templates/k8s.tpl")}"
    vars {
        k8s_master_name = "${join("\n", azurerm_virtual_machine.k8s-master.*.name)}"
    }
}

resource "local_file" "k8s_file" {
  content  = "${data.template_file.k8s.rendered}"
  filename = "./inventory/k8s-host"
}
```

### File k8s.tpl

```
[kube-master]
${k8s_master_name}
```

final result

```
[kube-master]
k8s-master-01
k8s-master-02
k8s-master-03
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me on aws ec2:

main.tf:

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  for_each      = toset(["ingress-01", "node-01", "node-02", "master-01" ])
  ami           = "ami-0c239ecd40dcc174c"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "${each.key}"
  }
}

resource "local_file" "inventory" {
  content = templatefile("inventory.tmpl", { content = tomap({
    for instance in aws_instance.instance:
      instance.tags.Name => instance.public_dns
    })
  })
  filename = format("%s/%s", abspath(path.root), "inventory.yaml")
}
```

template (inventory.tmpl):

```
all:
  children:
    ingress:
      hosts:
%{ for content_key, content_value in content }
%{~ if length(regexall("ingress", content_key)) > 0 ~}
        ${content_key}:
          ansible_host: ${content_value}
%{ endif ~}
%{~ endfor ~}
    master:
      hosts:
%{ for content_key, content_value in content }
%{~ if length(regexall("master", content_key)) > 0 ~}
        ${content_key}:
          ansible_host: ${content_value}
%{ endif ~}
%{~ endfor ~}
    nodes:
      hosts:
%{ for content_key, content_value in content }
%{~ if length(regexall("node", content_key)) > 0 ~}
        ${content_key}:
          ansible_host: ${content_value}
%{ endif ~}
%{~ endfor ~}
```

cat inventory.yaml

```
all:
  children:
    ingress:
      hosts:
        ingress-01:
          ansible_host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
    master:
      hosts:
        master-01:
          ansible_host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
    nodes:
      hosts:
        node-01:
           ansible_host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
        node-02:
           ansible_host: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach: from template to inventory file, use template_file to render the content and use local_file to output a file.

template file:

```
## file inventory.tpl

[frontend]
${bastion_pub_ip}

[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_private_key_file = ${key_path}
ansible_ssh_user = ubuntu
```

render and output:

```
## file inventory.tf

data "template_file" "inventory" {
    template = "${file("./test/inventory.tpl")}"

    vars {
       bastion_pub_ip = "${element(azurerm_public_ip.bastion.*.ip_address, count.index)}"
       key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
    }
}

resource "local_file" "save_inventory" {
  content  = "${data.template_file.inventory.rendered}"
  filename = "./myhost"
}
```

It works for single server, if you have a list, I don't find a proper way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Since march 2023, there is a [terraform provider for ansible](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/ansible/ansible/latest/docs), which allows you to create, among other things, groups and hosts.

You could declare your hosts and groups inside your terraform code like:

```
# declare your groups here
resource "ansible_group" "webservers" {
  name = "webservers"
  variables = {
    ansible_user = "ubuntu"
    some_var     = "my_variable"
  }
}

resource "ansible_group" "databases" {
  name = "databases"
  variables = {
    ansible_user     = "ubuntu"
    postgres_version = 14
  }
}

# declare your hosts here
resource "ansible_host" "os_compute_01" {
  name   = "os-compute-01.domain.tld"
  groups = [ansible_group.webservers.name]
}

resource "ansible_host" "db_01" {
  name   = "db-01.domain.tld"
  groups = [ansible_group.databases.name]
}
```

Once this terraform code is executed, these resources are stored to state, which can then be read by the [terraform inventory module for ansible](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cloud.terraform/blob/main/docs/cloud.terraform.terraform_provider_inventory.rst)

Your inventory file would look something like:

```yaml
---
plugin: cloud.terraform.terraform_provider
project_path: "path/to/your/terraform/dir"
```

> Note: You need to install the cloud.terraform collection in order to be able to use this inventory plugin

assuming you have the credentials in place to read the state file, this will result in the following inventory being read:

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts: {}
  children:
    webservers:
      vars:
        ansible_user: ubuntu
        some_var: my_variable
      hosts:
        os-compute-01.domain.tld:
    databases:
      vars:
        ansible_user: ubuntu
        postgres_version: 14
      hosts:
        db-01.domain.tld:
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
data "template_file" "ansible_inventory" {
  template = "${file("${path.module}/hosts.tmpl")}"

  vars = {
    public_ips = "${join("\n", aws_instance.public_instance.*.public_ip)}"
  }
}

resource "local_file" "hosts" {
  filename = "${path.module}/hosts"

  content = data.template_file.ansible_inventory.rendered
}
```