# Reference multiple aws_instance in terraform for template output

Tags: terraform

We want to deploy services into several regions.
Looks like because of the `aws` provider, we can't just use `count` or `for_each`, as the provider can't be interpolated. Thus I need to set this up manually:

```
resource "aws_instance" "app-us-west-1" {
   provider = aws.us-west-1
   #other stuff
}

resource "aws_instance" "app-us-east-1" {
  provider = aws.us-east-1
  #other stuff
}
```

I would like when running this to create a file which contains all the IPs created (for an ansible inventory).

I was looking at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788089/169252

and trying to adapt it for my case:

```
resource "local_file" "app-hosts" {
   content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/app_hosts.tpl",
     {
        hosts = aws_instance[*].public_ip
     }
   )
   filename = "app-hosts.cfg"
}
```

And then setting up the template accordingly.

But this fails:

```
Error: Invalid reference

  on app.tf line 144, in resource "local_file" "app-hosts":
 122:        hosts = aws_instance[*].public_ip

A reference to a resource type must be followed by at least one attribute
access, specifying the resource name
```

I am suspecting that I can't just reference all the `aws_instance` defined as above like this. Maybe to refer to all `aws_instance` in this file I need to use a different syntax.

Or maybe I need to use a module somehow. Can someone confirm this?

Using terraform `v0.12.24`

EDIT: The provider definitions use alias and it's all in the same `app.tf`, which I was naively assuming to be able to apply in one go with `terraform apply` (did I mention I am a beginner with `terraform`?):

```
  provider "aws" {
     alias  = "us-east-1"
     region = "us-east-1"
   }

  provider "aws" {
    alias  = "us-west-1"
    region = "us-west-1"
  }
```

Comment: How are you applying the config for the different provider regions? Is this consecutive applies with a different alias, multiple module declarations with different root config input aliases etc.?

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks for chiming in. I am a terraform beginner. I am using alias. I will edit the question to add some code, did not think this to be of importance.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to not do a `join` but simply listing them all individually:

```
 {
   host1 = aws_instance.app-us-west-1.public_ip
   host2 = aws_instance.app-us-east-1.public_ip
   # more hosts
 }
```