# Terraform create list

Tags: ansible, terraform, openstack, ansible-inventory, terraform-provider-openstack

I try to put all floating ips of my coturn servers in a ansible inventory.

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_cfg" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/hosts.tpl",
    {
      coturn = openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn[*].floating_ip
    }
  )
  filename = "../ansible/inventory/hosts.cfg"
}
```

**Error: This object does not have an attribute named "floating_ip".**

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_cfg" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/hosts.tpl",
    {
      coturn = openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn["coturn-1"].floating_ip
    }
  )
  filename = "../ansible/inventory/hosts.cfg"
}
```

**Works, but only for one instance.**

My template file.

```
[coturn]
%{ for ip in coturn ~}
${ip}
%{ endfor ~}
```

My openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2 definition.

```
resource "openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2" "coturn" {
  for_each = var.coturn_instance_names
  floating_ip = openstack_networking_floatingip_v2.coturn[each.key].address
  instance_id = openstack_compute_instance_v2.coturn[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: What is your definition of `openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2`?

Comment: You could workaround by setting `coturn = openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn` then in the template looping over the map and access `floating_ip` for each value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer to my question, but solves the problem.
I currently use this configuration, mentioned from zigarn.

```
resource "local_file" "hosts_cfg" {
  content = templatefile("${path.module}/templates/hosts.tpl",
    {
      coturn = openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn
    }
  )
  filename = "../ansible/inventory/hosts.ini"
}
```

```
[coturn]
%{ for instance in coturn ~}
${instance.floating_ip}
%{ endfor ~}
```

I still don't know, why this works([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61788089/15490090))

```
kafka_processors = aws_instance.kafka_processor.*.public_ip
```

but this does not

```
coturn = openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn.*.floating_ip
```

Comment: In your question you where using `openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn[*].floating_ip`, not `openstack_compute_floatingip_associate_v2.coturn.*.floating_ip`

Comment: I tried it in both ways. Sadly, they both did not work.